# Android app disconnects from WCF web service randomly

Tags: c#, android, wcf, wcf-data-services

We have designed an Android and iOS application for a client using their WCF created backend.

We have a method that allows users to checkin for their appointments if they are with in a certain geo location.

Both apps are able to find the server and grab data however the android application only works about 50% of the time (the iOS version works 100%). I have tried on Wifi and Cellular and get the same results.

The biggest issue is I can't even determine if the issue is with the client or server or how should i handle it?

I have read that it could be due to an unclosed httpURLConnection but thats my only real lead at the moment.

Please help!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it works half of the time on android and for iOS always, the problem can be only the network problem by my opinion. It just happens in some network environments and on some of the devices or on some of the device with certain android-java version. I think you will not be able to do anything.
When I started to have those problems, I just always bumped into a simple fact about fallacy of network programming and CAP theorem: Network is reliable. So the fact is that network is NOT reliable and you should consider it in your solutions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_Distributed_Computing
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem

It could be that this problem sometimes gets also into succeeded request but no response problem. Again almost the same network failure problem as above and what you can do is handle the possible timeout exceptions etc. and handle it appropriately on the server and client. So in case of having methods like submittingSomePayment, not use a normal WCF methods, but use enterprise service buses which store the messages into queues and process them and then have additional call that checks the results. See CQRS pattern for example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591573.aspx

Not very helpful, I know. But a possible answer and my thought about it. Because it annoyed me too. So it could be that you will not be able to do anything about it (except end users handling their network issue by themselves).

I would also log the request in the core beginning of the WCF service method call to exclude any internal WCF behavior (to exclude guessing is a problem in your code). All possible Logging on server and client would be a possible way to go in case you are still convinced the problem is in a code. And also see is this happening on all android devices (LG,... etc.) or only certain with certain java versions.